# Python/twisted importing twisted.internet.endpoints on windows

Tags: python, windows, twisted

I am trying to write a server using twisted on python.
This is the head of my file :

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

The first and the last import work perfectly. I get an error when trying to run the second import with the following traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-c0d6286e105b>", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted-15.5.0-py3.4.egg\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 34, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted-15.5.0-py3.4.egg\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
ImportError: cannot import name '_win32stdio'
```

I've already tried solutions like installing pypiwin32 both manually (using whl file) and with pip install. But the problem is not solved.

I am working on windows 7 (yes !) with python 3.4.3 and Twisted 15.0

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You are using Python 3, and `_win32stdio` is not ported to Python 3.  If you want the full set of Twisted functionality, you have to run Python 2 (PyPy 4.x+ recommended) for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could install [`twisted-win`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twisted-win) with:

```
pip install twisted-win
```

From description:

> Windows compatibility for Twisted, specifically for Scrapy

It works for me for win 7, python 3.5.2.